# android button fine text alignment

Tags: android, layout, button

I'm trying to create standard button in android with a background and some text in front but some fairly specific alignment. I want the text to be centered vertically and on the left with 20dp of padding. The alignment works but the padding doesn't. I know I could probably get the desired effect by putting a few spaces in the text but that seems like a hack and next I want to do a similar thing but with the text at the top so I would prefer a more elegant solution.
Here's what I have:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="312dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:id="@+id/gv_music_button"
        android:text="Music"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My mistake, padding was working correctly. Just didn't appear to be.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work if the button uses a patterned background.  The padding also effects the background which is probably not the desired effect